# Scraping amazon reviews including specific variables

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Basically, I would like to scrape a number of amazon reviews and write some code to scrape it including the variable "helpfulness votes". I've seen a lot of scraping tutorials but haven't encountered one where this variable has been scraped. Does anyone have an idea/recommendations? I'm very new to scraping..

So far I have encountered links like https://scrapfly.io/blog/how-to-scrape-amazon/. The problem is that most of the time they don't show how to scrap the variable "review helpfulness", i.e a column where the number of helpfulness votes per review is stored. Is there a way to get amazon reviews including this variable?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.